# "invalid, non monotonically increasing dts" error while writing streams to file with ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

I was finally able to write video stream packets to a file using the function

```
av_interleaved_write_frame(outputContext, &packet);
```

But after a short period of time I got this error:

```
Application provided invalid, non monotonically increasing dts to muxer 
in stream 0: *numberX* >= *numberY*
```

Does anybody have any idea, what's causing this and how to fix it?

Comment: your dts should be monotonically increasing. For example: 1, 2, 3. cannot be 1, 3, 2.

Answer (score 1):

set packet.pts to a correct value before calling av_interleaved_write_frame()
it's the time stamp in which this frame is presented (e.g displayed on the screen)

this value should be strictly increasing for each packet

Comment: This is a partial answer. Can you provide more info regarding "set packet.pts to a correct value before calling ..." ?

Comment: @MichaelIV it depends on the context. usually av_rescale family functions are used to calculate the correct pts